# Objective-C: How to dynamically create GUI objects?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

I`m really new in Objective-C and Mac OSX programming.

Can someone give me simple example for the next task:
I have array of strings (for example ('one','two','three','four')) in my app GUI each string should be represented by row, each row should has Label(with text of string) and CheckBox. Number of strings in array may be different. How i can dynamically create this GUI objects?

It is like in Transmission app, when you open torrent file and window opens with list of files and checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D you want to create a table? So what you are looking for is a UITableView object whose rows will be dynamically created after you set the 'data source'(in this case the data source can be your viewController that encapsulates that string array) from which it will get the data dynamically.

You'd better have a look at some documentation about [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [their programming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

If this is not what you are looking for, you can accomplish your goal by creating many [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) dynamically, adding content to them (UILabels, etc) and position them one after the other on the main UIView as subview calculating their frame position and dimension

Comment: Thank you. But your examples about iOS programming but i am asking about Mac OSX programming

Comment: His comments still apply.  Just substitute NSView for UIView or NSLabel for UILabel.  With that said, you can dynamically create GUI objects the same way as any other object - alloc/init.  However, the most common thing is to create multiple Nib files and load them as needed and retrieve objects from there.

Comment: pardon me, I supposed you were talking about iPhone& co. Here you are a doc for NStable view http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html and here is a tutorial http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableViewTutorial